# iOS MapKit, how to force low-res on retina?

Tags: mapkit

Is there a way to force MapKit to show (and so to download) only low resolution images even on retina displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have no control over this.  If you want this level of control you will need to bypass MapKit and use a library like [RouteMe](https://github.com/route-me/route-me)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm going to give it a try.